# Could not lookup DNS configuration info service: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

Tags: node.js, macos, forever, nodemailer

On a Mac OS X server 10.6.8, I have a Node server launched with *forever* **over SSH** using *nodemailer* configured with a SMTP on GandiMail.

Sometimes, when I try to send an e-mail, **it isn't delivered at all**, and an error show up in my forever.log :

> could not lookup DNS configuration info service: (ipc/send) invalid
>   destination port

What is going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given [this mail on Apple Mailing lists](http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2010/May/msg00000.html), it seems that the DNS stop to work as soon as the session over SSH is ended, even if the server was launched in background and detached from the shell with *forever*.

I solved it by remote logging on my server and launched my node.js server directly on a local terminal.

<sub>Note : if someone have a more suitable fix for this, please edit and add it to this answer.</sub>